# Using only one library in Java

Tags: java, jar, import

Is it possible for my project, to use only one library i made earlier for my program and still use functions from `import java.util.*;` ?

If yes, is there a way to include `java.util.*`  in my library?

I have it in my project like this:

```
import myLibrary.*;
import java.util.*;
```

and want it to be like this:

```
import myLibrary.*;
```

EDIT: 
The reason for this is because in our homework, it says that our program can include only one library we made earlier. Im not sure whether it means no other libraries literally and we must figure out how to reduce it to only myLibrary or its general knowledge, that java.util.*; doesnt count as an extra library?

The aim of this assignment is to learn making .jar libraries and including them, from java.util.*, im using only the scanner and other basic functions to get the input from user. We already had assignments for creating our own hash maps and implementing linked lists so i dont really think its about reinventhing the wheel in this case.

Solved: Thank you for your explanations guys, i was worried that importing java.util.*  was the same as importing entire library with it but since it only imports stuff from built in library in JDK, i guess it shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is it a purely academic question, or is there a reason you need this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: The java libraries are available trough the JRE, which is needed to execute your program in the first place. What could you possibly gain from this?

Comment: You can't be sure on which other library the jars you want to combine depend on so your task may be very difficult. But the way I understand your homework, is that you don't need to do that. Importing a package into a class is not the same as including a library in your project.

Comment: I think a key piece of knowledge that OP is missing is what @GameDroids just said: Libraries and `import` statements are not synonymous. You can have many `import` statements while still using only one library.

Comment: Yes, thats true, i considered them to be synonymous, sorry for making topic about such trivial thing, just wanted to be sure how things are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a classs (e.g. `java.util.List`), then you have two options:

1. Use its fully qualified class name (`java.util.List`)
2. Add an import statement for that class.

It's that simple.

Don't let the import statements worry you, most classes end up with lots of import statements. If you're using a decent IDE it will handle a lot of that stuff for you.

Edit: in response to the OP's edit: your tutor probably wants you to use your own classes (e.g. your own implementation of a vector) instead of reusing the classes in `java.util`, their idea was probably to give you experience of writing data structures. Whether importing `java.util.*` counts as another library depends on what your tutor meant.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The package to be used in the homework should obviously not use any other packages.

Comment: @HermanTorjussen well, yeah, it's wrong _now_ because the OP edited his post, but it was correct at the time the question was posted. Answer edited to hopefully be useful...

Answer (score 0):

`java.util` is a Java in build Java library and it is `rt.jar` file inside the `JDK`. If you really want to do this, you can find that `jar` file and use `maven` [packaging plug-in](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) and build a one `jar`.

But I am really confuse here what are you trying to archive.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to include any files in your project to use `java.util.*`.  Those files are included with the `JRE` and will work in any Java installation (assuming version compliance).

Simply create your own library and import it where needed.  It's safe to assume `java.util` is always available and included.

Answer (score 0):

Following the guideline of your homework, you should only use the one package that you have written yourself. That excludes any usage or imports of `java.util` and its members, as that would be two packages used in total. The `java.lang` package is by default imported into the namespace of all Java programs, so that doesn't count.

This kind of requirement in programming assignments is common when learning to implement basic data structures, algorithms and the like. By reinventing the wheel, you as a student learn more.